# Labeling Contour Lines in fcontour in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, contour

I'm trying to figure out how to label the contour lines of a figure in Matlab when the contour lines were plotted with fcontour.  Is there a way to do this?  I looked through the function contour properties [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.function.functioncontour-properties.html), but I couldn't find a way to do this.  I also looked into using [clabel](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clabel.html#btp62m6), but it appears that it only works for contour, contour3, or contour.

Note: Originally I tried to plot the function using a contour but I was running out of memory on my machine that has 32GB of RAM.  I even tried reducing the number of points to 100 x 100 or 10,000 points and I was still running out of memory when I tried to plot.

Edit:

Here's a copy of the code that was making my machine crash.

```html
clc; close all; clear all;
x1 = linspace(0, 20, 100);
x2 = logspace(log10(1E-3), log10(20), 100);
[xx1, xx2] = ndgrid(x1, x2);
factor1 = xx1 ./ (xx1 .* xx2 + 100 * xx2);
contour( xx2, factor1, xx1, 'ShowText', 'on');
set(gca, 'XScale', 'log', 'YScale', 'log');
ylim([1E-9 1E-6]);
```

I did some additional analysis and it appears that the part that's making the machine choke is the changing of the ylim.

Comment: Can you post your code, it's weird that you run out of memory with such a low amount of points.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and include the output?

Comment: Possibly relevant posts controlling labels on contour lines: [especially this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52880345/8239061) and maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55469820/8239061) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250583/8239061) is perhaps tangentially related.